# How to hide Error message on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am working on a web site, where i have a login page, on wrong credentials it shows a message on div , but i need to hide this message after i refresh the same error page. I am new to JQuery Javascipt and need to implement this feature anyhow.

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <div class="alert alert-error text-center">
        ${error}
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

**Added:**

Or is there any other way to redirect this page to another page(login) on Refresh.?

Please help on above.

Comment: Do you use any Javascript framework? JQuery?

Comment: `window.onunload = unloadPage;
function unloadPage()
{
    $('.alert-error').hide();
}`

Comment: yes, I am using jQuery.

Comment: If it is refreshing, `window.onunload` will fire.

Comment: @RajarshiDas this would try to hide it on current page, not once refreshed

Comment: So your issue comes from `${not empty error}` not being reseted. But we have no idea what this variable is?!

Comment: you need to set empty that error variable once you showed the error.

Comment: @A.Wolff "${not empty error}" is an server side error message

Comment: @rajuvaishnav Ya sure but you didn't provided any relevant code regarding it. You need to reset it before render client side HTML. BTW, we don't know what this error is relevant to. Server side error or rsulting from any user interaction client side? You have to improve your question somehow

Comment: @A.Wolff, yes it is dependent on the server for rendering the message, but i asked above issue whether we can hide it at client side on refresh. I am new to jquery javascipt so dont know much, but somehow i need to prepare this feature.

Comment: Or , if any other way to redirect page to another page on refresh.

Comment: @rajuvaishnav You'd have better instead to explain why would you need to hide it on refresh? How would you differenciate first load compare to refresh one? Etc... See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.alert-error').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Comment: But then how the error message could be displayed client side? Error is shown depending `test="${not empty error}">` which is checked server side before rendering HTML client side

Answer (score 0):

You can hide this using cookie and jquery. 
When your page load then set the cookie value **true** after that , whenever page reloads then check the cookie value using jquery and show the message according the cookie ,
you can use jquery plugin [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

By this you can access the cookie and manage the error div with jquery to hide and show the error div.